# Amazon EC2 and jbossws

Tags: java, wsdl, jaxb, amazon-ec2, jbossws

I've deployed a webservice to a Jboss instance running on Amazon EC2. The webservice works fine locally, but when I deploy on EC2, and go to the /jbossws/services page the Endpoint Address for the webservice is the private DNS of the ec2 instance (domU-X-X-X-X etc...), not the public dns (which I would like it to be).

I've tried loading the wsdl by changing the private hostname to the public IP; that works, but when I try to call any of the operations I get a HostNotFoundException, I'm guessing due to the fact that the generated wsdl has the stanza:

`<service name='XXXService'> 
     <port binding='tns:XXXBinding' name='XXXPort'> 
        <soap:address location='http://domU-XX-XX-XX-XX-XX-XX.compute-1.internal:8080/xx/xx/xx'/> 
     </port> 
 </service>`

where http://domU-XX-XX-XX-XX-XX-XX.compute-1.internal is the internal dns of the ec2 instance.

The wsdl is auto generated - Is there a JAXB annotation I can use so that I can force the generated wsdl to use the public dns of the EC2 instance?

Many thanks -

Answer (score 0):

In JBoss 5.1.0 GA look at
jbossws.deployer/META-INF/jboss-beans.xml
and comment the following line
${jboss.bind.address}

it is 100% worked

or see the following
http://community.jboss.org/wiki/JBossWS-UserGuide